# Objective-c iphone programming with cisco routers?

Tags: iphone, xcode, router, cisco, cisco-ios

I've seen some apps that connect to routers via ssh.

Can anyone recommend any documentation on interacting with Cisco IOS configs and notifications? I'd love to write some custom in-house code!

Answer (score 1):

Most of the configuring/querying can be done via SNMP, so you don't have to have a SSH client/command parser built in you application. What's supported depends on router/ios version. You can check here: [SNMP OID Browser](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en). SNMP can sometimes be overwhelming, but in time it can be of great use to you. My first suggestion is to find a SNMP browser (eg. from solarwinds) so you can inspect what info you can get from the router. Then you can use [NET-SNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org/) library to do the actual querying/configuring of the router, or if you are willing to pay you can try [IP*Works](http://www.nsoftware.com/portal/macos/).